# The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parame with the name 'title'.",

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

my fried is making a traveller app then we face this error in every title line(The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'title'.",)

```
  title: SizedBox.shrink(),//The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'title'.",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.local_pizza,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                title: SizedBox.shrink(),//The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'title'.",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 15.0,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('http://i.imgur.com/zL4Krbz.jpg'),
                ),
                title: SizedBox.shrink(),//The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'title'.",
          )
        ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BottomNavigationBarItem does not have a title field.

***It has a label field.***

You can check the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html).

Also, since the label is of String? type, you cannot put a Widget there.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.local_pizza,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                label: "Your label"
              ),
```